# Unable to get unique xpath of date webelement

Tags: java, xml, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to select date (`08 March 2017`) in following website using `xpath` locator:

https://www.yatra.com/

Now when I click on the origin Date and use the below `xpath` to get the date:

```
//a[@id='a_2017_3_13' AND @class ='datetext']
```

I am getting `7` matching nodes and unable to get unique `xpath` and unable to select the date . 
How can i get unique `Xpath` for the date?

Comment: try this xpath. `//a[@id='a_2017_3_13'][@class='datetext']`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that there are really 7 elements with same `id`. You can use following `XPath` that seem to work:

```
//div[@id='PegasusCal-0-month-3-2017']//a[@id='a_2017_3_8' and @class ='datetext']
```

You just need to replace month and year in `div` element `id` 
as well as date in `a` elements' `id` every time you need to set new date

Comment: this seems to work. So every time I have to reconstruct my xpath to make my code dynamic for any month and date..

Comment: Yes, you should make changes to both parts (`div` and `a`) each time you need to select new date. Please mark this answer as `Accepted` if it solved your issue. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You might be using correct `xpath` but the issue is use `AND` operator in small case in `xpath`

Like -

```
//a[@id='a_2017_3_13' and @class ='datetext']
```

Other then this still have more then one matching node with the same You can try with indexes

like-

```
//a[@id='a_2017_3_13' and @class ='datetext'][1]
```

Comment: Agreed! i already did add the indexes.. its still showing 7 matching nodes. i am not sure what exactly the problem is>